# XML XMLNS ending with "important" #

Tags: xml, firefox-addon, xml-namespaces

In Mozilla Extensions file called `install.rdf`, there is a line saying

```
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
```

Are those `#` chars important, or what is their purpose?

see: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/install_manifests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fragment identifier is part of the URL (so yes, it's important) and indicates that the URL refers to an abstract resource rather than a document. This is part of the RDF standard, at least as it was formulated back when the install.rdf format was designed in the late 1990's. See http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html for an explanation, in particular:

> It is important, on the Semantic Web, to be clear about what is
>   identified. An http: URI (without fragment identifier) necessarily
>   identifies a generic document. This is because the HTTP server
>   response about a URI can deleiver a rendition of (or location of, or
>   apologies for) a document which is identified by the URI requested. A
>   client which understands the http: protocol can immediately conclude
>   that the fragementid-less URI is a generic document. This is true even
>   if the publisher (owner of the DNS name) has decided not to run a
>   server. Even if it just records the fact that the document is not
>   available online, still a client knows it refers to a document. This
>   means that identifiers for arbitrary RDF concepts should have fragment
>   identifiers. This, in turn, means that RDF namespaces should end with
>   "#".

Like so much about RDF, this is pretty unintuitive and hard to understand (at least for me). My advice is to treat the namespace URLs as opaque strings and not worry about them too much.

Comment: nice definition fragment of fragment definition :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, an XML namespace is just a URI. This is the case. The rest is convention.

I guess the reason is that many identifiers in RDF are made up of the namespace concatenated with a name so you get things like

- http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property or
- http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class

And yeah, the trailing `#` are important. Namespaces have to be exact.